# Find example where $f$ is not measurable

Tags: real-analysis

Give one example where $\{x: f(x) = \alpha\}$ is measurable for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, but $f$ is not measurable.

Answer (score 3):

Let $E$ be a nonmeasureable set and let 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^x&\text{if }x\in E\\-e^x&\text{if }x\notin E\end{cases}$$

Comment: Note that $\{x:f(x) = \alpha\} = \begin{cases}\{\ln \alpha\} & \ln\alpha \in E, \alpha > 0\\\{\ln(-\alpha)\}& \ln(-\alpha)\notin E, \alpha < 0\\\emptyset&\text{else}\end{cases}$